# DOM CSS Cross Browser Library

Tags: javascript, css

I normally work with jQuery, which takes away most of the cross browser pain (although not, unfortunately, all).  However, it doesn't seem to have any support for manipulation of the CSS DOM, and this still seems to be a bit of a minefield - [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) has some information.

Our application allows users to theme their site to some extend by generating a CSS stylesheet with the colours that they have selected.  It's pretty straightforward, but I'd like to let them "preview" it by applying the changes directly to the CSS DOM, before having them save it back to the database and generating the CSS file.

Does anyone know of a library which will make cross browser CSS DOM maniuplation easier?  Just so we're clear, I'm *not* trying to change the css rules on an element, or set of elements (like with $.css()), or to add/remove classes. I would like to modify the stylesheets directly.

Comment: jQuery style selectors on the CSS DOM would be pretty wicked too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend the [YUI stylesheet utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/stylesheet/). I haven't seen any other libraries with as much functionality or as clean an interface.

Comment: Looks like the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add or replace a `<style>` element in the main document's DOM, and fill it with the generated CSS?

Comment: Possibly, but it would require that all of the new rules have a higher precedence than the old ones, or I would have to disable the old stylesheet completely (and would therefore have to reproduce all of the rules, including the ones I wasn't modifying).  It seemed to me that modifying the existing stylesheet should be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way, is to create a .jsp .php or whatever you're using which accepts colour parameters, which in turn renders a .css output with colours replaced.

Use JavaScript to make a request with colour parameters and append the css script to the page.

It is possible to do it directly on the styleSheet object, though this will take more time and create more maintenance. Everytime you want to change your custom stylesheet you actually use for production, you will also have to change the preview version. Ergo discrepancies will ensue.

Just reuse the stylesheet template you're going to use for production anyways.

Comment: Doesn't scale well if I want to dynamically change the colour as the user changes it on a colour picker; I might generate hundreds of requests a second...  Otherwise, yes, that would be easy as it's essentially what I do to make the stylesheet after they save their changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like:

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
```

This disabled the first stylesheet of the current page. Maybe if you play around with it you can resolve your problem.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid; lots of different behaviour on different browsers, and I'm too lazy for that :)  I want something that will take away the pain instead.

Comment: Well, I tried this and it is working on IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera. I think that this can be considered as cross-browser solution.

Comment: Yes, this one bit of DOM manipulation is cross browser, but it's only one bit - not anywhere near everything I want to do.  In general, CSS DOM support is _not_ cross browser friendly.